# Mysql select data from multiple foreign keys pointing to the same table

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables:

modules:

```
+-------------+---------+
| Field       | Type    |
+-------------+---------+
| id          | int(11) |
| title       | int(11) | <- foreign key to texts
| description | int(11) | <- foreign key to texts
| goal        | int(11) | <- foreign key to texts
| sp1         | int(11) | <- foreign key to texts
| sp2         | int(11) | <- foreign key to texts
+-------------+---------+
```

texts:

```
+---------+--------------+
| Field   | Type         |
+---------+--------------+
| id      | int(11)      |
| name    | varchar(100) |
| text    | text         |
| is_html | tinyint(1)   |
+---------+--------------+
```

With this:

```
SELECT modules.title, modules.description from modules;
```

I only get the id's of the row from `texts`.

How can I query the value of the `text` field from `texts`?

Many other answers only have one foreign key, or foreign keys in different tables.

Edit: Some text are used multiple times.

Comment: You need to join the `texts` table once for every FK. But what ist the reason for this design?

Comment: Why aren't you just storing the text fields in your modules table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this design you have to join the `texts` table once for every mapped text field. In your case, for `title` and `description` it would be:

```sql
SELECT title.text as title, descr.text as description
FROM modules
JOIN texts as title on title.id = modules.title
JOIN texts as descr on descr.id = modules.description
```

This might be fine if the number of such queries is limited. But if you have a lot of them, I would rethink the design.

However, if you have very good reasons for this design, consider to map the texts in PHP using an array which caches the `texts` table.

For example: Every time you update the `texts` table, you fetch the data and store it in a cache file like `cache/texts.php` which looks like

```
<?php
const TEXTS = array(
    1 => 'some title',
    2 => 'some description',
    // ...
);
```

Then you can write a function like

```
function getText($textId) {
    require_once 'cache/texts.php';
    return TEXTS[$textId];
}
```

and use it like

```
echo '<td>' . getText($row[title]) . '</td>';
```

Or with a template engine it look like

```
<td>{{ module.title|getText }}</td>
<td>{{ module.description|getText }}</td>
```

This might be not the best solution. But it's a simple one and can save you a lot of JOINs in SQL.